# "You can't sign in here with a personal account. Use your work or school account instead" when trying to access Dynamics CRM api

Tags: c#, azure-active-directory, dynamics-crm, microsoft-dynamics

I already tried the following:
.I set the Supported account types: All Microsoft account users
.In the Manifest file I changed :

```
"allowPublicClient": true,
"signInAudience": "AzureADandPersonalMicrosoftAccount",
```

.I granted admin consent about permissions and consent

Im following the code I found in documentation

```
            #region Authentication

            var authBuilder = PublicClientApplicationBuilder.Create(clientId)
                             .WithAuthority(AadAuthorityAudience.AzureAdMultipleOrgs)
                             .WithRedirectUri(redirectUri)
                             .Build();
            var scope = resource + "/.default";
            string[] scopes = { scope };

            AuthenticationResult token =
                authBuilder.AcquireTokenInteractive(scopes).ExecuteAsync().Result;
            #endregion Authentication
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I created an **Azure AD Multi-Tenant Application** (*Accounts in any organizational directory (Any Azure AD directory - Multitenant) and personal Microsoft accounts*):

[image]

Granted **Dynamic CRM API permission**:

[image]

For ***sample***, I used the below endpoint to **authorize users**:

```json
https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/v2.0/authorize? 
client_id=ClientID
&response_type=code  
&redirect_uri=https://jwt.ms
&response_mode=query  
&scope=https://admin.services.crm.dynamics.com/user_impersonation
&state=12345
```

And ***I got the same error while trying to sign-in with Personal account***:

[image]

> **Note** that: Dynamics CRM API is used in a business or enterprise context, where must have work or school accounts that are associated with an Azure AD tenant.

- Microsoft accounts created for personal use are normally not linked to an Azure AD tenant.
- They lack the same level of security and control as accounts from work or school as a result, Personal Microsoft Accounts cannot access enterprise or company tools like Dynamics CRM.
- Hence, Dynamics CRM allows access to work or school accounts to prevent unauthorized access and protect sensitive data.

I tried to **sign-in with Work Account**, and is successfully signed-in :

[image]

[image]

I am able to generate **access token** successfully using below parameters via Postman:

```json
https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/v2.0/token

client_id:ClientID
grant_type:authorization_code
scope:https://admin.services.crm.dynamics.com/user_impersonation
code:code
redirect_uri:https://jwt.ms
client_secret:ClientSecret
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: So long story short I have to loging using a work account?  How can i create one if i dont have it?

Comment: Go to Azure Active Directory -> Users -> New User. Check this https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/itops-talk-blog/what-s-the-difference-between-a-personal-microsoft-account-and-a/ba-p/2241897

Comment: thanks adding a new user solved my problem of loging in, any idea how to solve this probleme im getting after loging in?  AADSTS7000218 The request body must contain the following parameter: 'client_assertion' or 'client_secret'.

Comment: Create an Client Secret in the Azure AD Application and pass it in the request. Go to Azure Active Directory -> App Registerations -> Your app -> Certificates and Secrets